# pip fails with AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'wraps'

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, fedora-21

I'm on Fedora. I recently upgraded my system from F20 to F21. Pip was working fine on F20 but after the upgrade to F21 something must have gone wrong. Pip stopped working, every time I enter the command `pip <anything>` the error below occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip import main
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from pip.commands import commands, get_summaries, get_similar_commands
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pip.commands.bundle import BundleCommand
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/bundle.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pip.commands.install import InstallCommand
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 5, in <module>
    from pip.req import InstallRequirement, RequirementSet, parse_requirements
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .req_install import InstallRequirement
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 31, in <module>
    from pip.utils import (
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 59, in <module>
    def rmtree(dir, ignore_errors=False):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/retrying.py", line 47, in wrap
    @six.wraps(f)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'wraps'
```

Comment: do you have two versions of six?

Comment: I'm not sure. How do I go about checking that without `pip list`?

Comment: `pip show six` , have you tried `pip install -U six`?

Comment: pip doesn't seem to work. Any command to do with pip shows the above error.

Comment: sorry yes, have you tried reinstalling pip? https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py

Comment: `wraps` was added to `six` in 1.7 (current version is 1.9).  It looks like you somehow reverted to an older version of `six`.  Or you have two versions of `six` and you're now pointed at the wrong one.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yes tried that several times. After removing pip and doing `python get-pip.py` the following is shown: 
`Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

Comment: @StevenRumbalski how do I correct that?

Answer (score 14):

Okay after trying out all the solutions I could google with no result in sight. I tried to risk and play a little bit. This might not be the safest solution but it worked fine for me.
Seeing that `python get-pip.py` resulted in:

```
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

even when I had pip uninstalled.
I went over to `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/` to find out two pip directories: **`pip`** and **`pip-6.0.8.dist-info`**. Removed both immediately. Then tried `python get-pip.py` again. Voila! it worked.

Comment: This worked for me too, but I had to delete the existing pip package from my virtualenv, not the global Python dist-packages.

Answer (score 8):

Use easy_install to install a prior version of pip

```
easy_install pip==7.0.2
```

Then use pip to install the version you came down from, in my case it was 9.0.1

```
pip install pip==9.0.1
```

Answer (score 7):

happend to me on windows with activestate python fresh install
I've just used easy_install to downgrade the pip

```
easy_install pip==7.1.2
```

and then it was working....

Answer (score 5):

If you **recreate** a virtual env that contains a **different pip**-version you can run into such a scenario:

```sh
# virtualenv /tmp/env
New python executable in /tmp/env/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip...done.

# /tmp/env/bin/pip install --upgrade pip
(...)
Found existing installation: pip 1.5.6
  Uninstalling pip:
    Successfully uninstalled pip
Successfully installed pip

# virtualenv /tmp/env
New python executable in /tmp/env/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip...done.

# /tmp/env/bin/pip install --upgrade pip
(...)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'wraps'
```

The environment now contains the pip fragments from the previous installation. To fix that you can use the **--clean** option:

```sh
# virtualenv --clear /tmp/env
Deleting tree /tmp/env/lib/python2.7
Not deleting /tmp/env/bin
New python executable in /tmp/env/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip...done.
```

Then virtualenv will wipe out the path before it installs the new environment.

If you wanna have an update behavior you can skip virtualenv if (e.g.) bin/python) is present.

```sh
# [ ! -x /tmp/env/bin/python ] && virtualenv /tmp/env
```

Answer (score 1):

This occurred in my situation after I had moved the virtualenv directory (along with the project) to a new location, which I clearly shouldn't have done as (reading the doc now) the manual clearly states some [full] hardcoded paths are included in the environment.

Deleting the bin/, include/, lib/ and lib64/ directories and then recreating the virtualenv solved the issue for me.

I did look into searching for and fixing the full paths in the environment, but fixing it everywhere (besides in the bin/activate* files) didn't seem trivial.

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
mv /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip* ./
yum reinstall python-pip
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Mac OS, but was able to fix this error by doing `mkvirtualenv --system-site-packages XXXX` as opposed to `mkvirtualenv XXXX`.

Running `pip install -r requirements.txt` in the virtual environment was giving me `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'wraps'` before and doesn't anymore.