# Installed python 2.7.9 instead of 3.4.3 and can't run pip install in cmd anymore

Tags: python, python-2.7, cmd

I installed python 2.7.9 instead of 3.4.3 due to module xlutils not working on 3.4.3 and from the time I installed python 2.7.9 and I just can't install the related modules to it by using pip install and I added the ;C:\Python27 to the system path.
what am I missing here coz it keeps on telling me this error:
'pip is not recognized as an internal or external command

Comment: pip only started coming standard in Python 3.4. For 3.3 and below you will have to install it yourself. https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html

Comment: @Alecg_O pip should come as standard for 2.7.9 no need to install it on top.

Comment: did you uninstall py 3.4?

Comment: I used to have 3.4.3 but coz I wanted to work with xlutils I installed python 2.7.9

Comment: Pip.exe is in my Python27/Scripts folder already

Comment: My point was more that you should uninstall python 3.4 if you won't use it, just to be safe and make sure the pip from 3.4 doesn't clash with 2.7

Comment: @Scironic Yes I unistalled it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pip is not in `C:\Python27`.

It's in `C:\Python27\Scripts`.

Check that folder to make sure there is a pip.exe, if there is then it should have installed fine, and make sure that `C:\Python27\Scripts` is in your `PATH`.

Comment: I have pip.exe inC:\Python27\Scripts
and the path you mean the "System path" or "User Path" ?

Comment: I added the C:\Python27\Scripts to system path by appending that at the end of the system path but it now tells me
"Attribute Error: 'module' object has no attribute 'wraps'

Comment: Yep I meant the system path. how are you calling pip?

Comment: Also post the full traceback if possible.

Comment: In cmd I type in the first line:
pip install "package name"

Comment: and whats the traceback?

Comment: Doing a little digging I found these two links: https://ask.openstack.org/en/question/56412/juno-devstack-install-failure-attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-wraps/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29038889/searched-everywhere-but-cant-seem-to-find-a-solution-to-attributeerror-mo they both suggest you have conflicting installs of a package somewhere. It may be worth uninstalling 2.7, deleting the directory, and then re-installing. Or you can find which package is causing the conflict.

Comment: It say: "Attribute Error: 'module' object has no attribute 'wraps

Comment: Oh I do have 2 Pip folders indeed ill try removing them and trying again!

Comment: I re-installed Python 2.7.9 after uninstalling it and deleting all it's related files and it worked good again and yes there was conflictions in too many libraries.
Thank you @Scironic

Comment: No problem! Don't forget to accept the answer so people in the future will know where to look.